# Is self.target = equivalent to [self setTarget] for a synthesised property?

Tags: objective-c

I have some doubts about this code:

```
@interface Foo {
    id target_;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) id target;
```

---

```
@implementation Foo

@synthesize target = target_;

-(id)initWithTarget:(id)t {
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        self.target = t;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [target release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

Questions:

- Is `self.target = t` exactly equivalent to `[self setTarget:t]`?

  - If yes, what about `target = t`?
  - If yes, `target` is retained, right?
- It would be perfectly fine to call `self.target = nil` in the `dealloc` method, right? Because the setter will release `target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is self.target = t exactly equivalent to [self setTarget:t]?

Yes. `self.target =` is pretty much equivalent to `setTarget:`. In some situations they will both compile to exactly the same binary, in other situations `self.target =` will have subtle differences that will make it execute faster than `setTarget:` but behave the same way.

> If yes, what about target = t?

No, it's not the same. You should avoid doing `target_ =` — this approach is accessing the C pointer directly which can cause all kinds of problems. There are some edge cases where you need to do this, but in general it should be avoided whenever possible.

> If yes, target is retained, right?

If you have ARC *disabled*, and it's declared as `retain` then `self.target =` and `setTarget:` will retain but `target_ =` will not retain and is likely to cause a crash later. If the property is not declared as `retain` it will never retain.

If you have ARC enabled and it`s declared as`strong`then all three styles of setter will retain the variable. If it's declared as something else (such as`weak`) it will not retain in all three cases.

> It would be perfectly fine to call self.target = nil in the dealloc method, right? Because the setter will release target.

The general advice is not to use `self.target =` or `setTarget:` inside dealloc. Use `[target_ release]; target_ = nil`. Or even better, enable ARC and do not do anything in with target in dealloc.

Comment: About the last answer, you meant `[target_ release]; target_ = nil` right?

Comment: @JustKidding yeah, I figured that was probably a mistake in your question. by `target = nil` I mean setting the ivar directly via `target_ = nil`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Is `target_ = nil` necessary? I mean, isn't it nilled out anyway upon dealloc?

Comment: No, dealloc won't nil anything out because setting it to nil consumes more CPU cycles than just leaving it as whatever value it was until something overwrites that part of memory. Setting to nil is a rarely needed precaution but in modern objective-c it's considered best practice, just incase something still has a pointer to that section of memory (which would be a bug). If you set it to nil, and such a bug does occur, it usually won't cause any problems because a buggy pointer to nil is often harmless. It's up to you. Strictly speaking, release is the only thing needed.

Answer (score 2):

- Yes. The documentation has an [entire section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) on how synthesized properties work.

  - `target = t` won't work because there is neither an instance variable nor a local variable called `target`.

    To set the property, you *must* use either `self.target = t` or `[self setTarget:t]`.

    You can still access the ivar directly using `target_` since that's how it's declared in your header, but naturally doing so will not fire the accessors.
  - It's only retained if you make sure you assign using the property setter, and the property is declared as retain/strong (which it is by default).
- If you're not using ARC to manage your references (which you really should), you should release ivars manually in `-dealloc`, not set their properties to nil:

  ```
  -(void) dealloc {
      [target_ release];
      [super dealloc];
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `self.target = t` is exactly equivalent to `[self setTarget:t]`.

`target = t` syntax will not work; dot-syntax is required. `target_ = t` will, but it will not be the same thing: no method is called, KVO observers are not notified, and the value is not retained.

Synthesized setter for `retain` property will automatically release previous value and retain the new one.

`self.target = nil` can be used instead of release in dealloc, but I strongly don't recommend that:

- it will not work for `assign` properties (in case their ivars do need to be released for some reason)
- not every ivar that needs to be released will have a property, so your dealloc will end up as mixture of `release` and assignments anyway
- a custom setter may have unwanted side effects
- when your primary (and only!) intent is to release an object, you should send it `release` message, instead of doing some indirect call which has a side effect of doing what you needed.